# Groovy equivalent for Java 8 Lambda Expression

Tags: java, groovy, lambda, closures, java-8

I have got this Java Interface with only one method.

```
// Java Interface
public interface AuditorAware {
    Auditor getCurrentAuditor();
}
```

I was using Java 8 Lambda expression to create insance of `AuditorAware` as following.

```
// Java 8 Lambda to create instance of AuditorAware
public AuditorAware currentAuditor() {
    return () -> AuditorContextHolder.getAuditor();
}
```

I am trying to write above Java implementation in Groovy.

I see there are many ways to implement interfaces in groovy as shown in this **[Groovy ways to implement interfaces](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+way+to+implement+interfaces)** documentation.

I have implemented above Java code to groovy equivalent by using implement interfaces with a map as shown in above mentioned documentation.

```
// Groovy Equivalent by "implement interfaces with a map" method
AuditorAware currentAuditor() {
    [getCurrentAuditor: AuditorContextHolder.auditor] as AuditorAware
}
```

But Implement interfaces with a closure method seems more concise as shown in documentation example. However, when I try to implement as follows, `IntelliJ` shows errors saying **Ambiguous Code Block**.

```
// Groovy Equivalent by "implement interfaces with a closure" method ???
AuditorAware currentAuditor() {
    {AuditorContextHolder.auditor} as AuditorAware
}
```

How can I change a Java 8 lambda implementation to groovy equivalent by using "implement interfaces with a closure" method?

Comment: have you tried specifying the closure without leaving the -> out?{ -> AuditorContextHolder.auditor }  also as is not necessary if you are using Groovy 2.2+

Comment: @DylanBijnagte Thanks. That worked. Also, I'm using `groovy 2.3.6`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by [Dylan Bijnagte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457622/groovy-equivalent-for-java-8-lambda-expression?noredirect=1#comment41555643_26457622), following code worked.

```
// Groovy Equivalent by "implement interfaces with a closure" method 
AuditorAware currentAuditor() {
    { -> AuditorContextHolder.auditor} as AuditorAware
}
```

Section *Paramter Notes* of [Documentation on Groovy Closure](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures) explain this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.&` operator to get a method reference:

```
class Auditor { 
  String name 
}

interface AuditorAware { 
  Auditor getCurrentAuditor() 
}

class AuditorContextHolder {
  static getAuditor() { new Auditor(name: "joe") }
}

AuditorAware currentAuditor() {
  AuditorContextHolder.&getAuditor
}

assert currentAuditor().currentAuditor.name == "joe"
```

In Java 8 you can use the `::` for method references:

```
  AuditorAware currentAuditor() {
    return AuditorContextHolder::getAuditor;
  }
```